# Como pegar o Array gerado da função print_r() para enviar no email?

Tags: php, array

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de logs e preciso pegar os dados gerados pelo [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php), para enviar no email caso ocorra algum erro na API, desta forma os desenvolvedores serão avisados, já contendo todo os dados, inclusive o array.

Grato!

Comment: Qual é o problema? `$log = print_r($objeto, true);` dessa forma ele não é exibido e sim armazenado em `$log`.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, nem reparei que tinha este parâmetro. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar a saida/estrutura de alguma variável com o `print_r()` informe o segundo argumento como `true`, dessa forma a função retorna a estrutura da variável passada no lugar de imprimir na tela.

```
<?php
   $arr = range(1,5);
   $log = print_r($arr, true);
```